# Receiving data from a DialogFragment if you're calling from an Activity vs a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

I call my DialogFragment like so:

If I am in an Activity:

```
MyDialogFragment dialogfragment = new MyDialogFragment();
dialogfragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
```

If I am already in a Fragment:

```
MyDialogFragment dialogfragment = new MyDialogFragment();
dialogfragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "");
```

In MyDialogFragment, which inflates an XML and allows the user to input some values to EditTexts and so forth, I want to be able to return those values back to wherever I called the dialog from.

For the sake of the question let's say my dialog class wants to return some private variables `String mName` and `int mValue`.

Is there a proper way to do this without knowing where the dialog is being called from (either an Activity or a Fragment)? How do I pass the values back / how do I receive them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send data to `activity` from `fragment`. You can do that by calling `public` method of `activity` by:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).sendData(Object object);
```

You can't do the same for sending data to a `fragment`.

As doc says:

> All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

What you should do is:

1. Define an `Interface` in the fragment.
2. Implement that `Interface` in the `activity`
3. Deliver data to the `activity`
4. then `activity` will deliver data to some other `fragment`.

BTW, you can also use this practice to send data to `activity` (upto point 3).

[Reference and example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Defining an interface:

```
public interface DataListener {
    public void onDataReceived(Object obj);
}
```

inside the `fragment`:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    DataListener  callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);

       // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
       // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
       try {
           callback = (DataListener) activity;
       } catch (ClassCastException e) {
           throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement DataListener");
       }
   }
}
```

Sending data from `fragment`;

```
callback.onDataReceived(object); // some object data
```

Receiving data in `activity`:

```
public static class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements DataListener{

   public void onDataReceived(Object object) {
      // Do something here with object data
   }
}
```

Now if you want, you can send this data to any other `fragment`.

Sending data from `activity` to some other `fragment`:

```
AnotherFragment anotherFrag = (AnotherFragment)
 getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if (anotherFrag != null) {
        anotherFrag.receiveDataInFrag(object);
    }else{
       // create a new instance of the fragment and pass data to it.
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that to send to an activity, you have to call some public receiving function of that activity class? Would I have to name every receiver function something like "sendData" in case I want some other activity to call this dialogfragment?

Comment: if there are **two** activities which can create a `fragment` **F**, then yes both need to have a public function to receive the data. Or incase you are following second option (using interface, which I personally recommend), you will have to implement the interface in both the activities.

Comment: I am reading that reference but find it really hard to follow. I am trying to make this code as modular as I can. Do I only need to implement one Interface in the DialogFragment, and that's all? Then for every activity/fragment that I call the DialogFragment from, I implement the Interface?

Comment: Also where would I actually write the interface / place it? In its own .java file of the same name?

Comment: @SeanHill, can place it either separately (in its own .java file) or even inside `fragment`. Your call. In my example, its is outside (its own java file).

Comment: What would I call from the OnClick method of the DialogFragment (to actually relay the data back to the calling activity/fragment)

Comment: this `callback.onDataReceived(object);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107981/discussion-between-rohit-arya-and-sean-hill).

Answer (score 2):

Create a callback interface and have pass it into your dialogfragment

```
interface DialogValuesCallback {
   void callThisFunctionWhenUserClicksOnOkInDialog(String passinmName,int passinmValue);
}
```

You can have your Activity or Fragment implement this interface.

Have a constructor in your MyDialogFragment which accepts the interface and assigns it to an member variable.

```
MyDialogFragment(DialogValuesCallback activityOrFragmentWhichImplementsThis){
    mInterfaceCallbackObjectRef = activityOrFragmentWhichImplementsThis;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to create a new constructor for each activity/fragment that could possibly call the dialogfragment?

Comment: The constructor sits within MyDialogFragment. You have to pass in an instance of wherever you implement the interface.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is that let's say I have a mix of activities and fragments (say 20 of them) that could be calling this DialogFragment. Do I have to add 20 different constructors to the DialogFragment class?

Comment: Nope, if you look at the constructor that i've shown, it is not of type of activity or fragment. It is only an interface. So anywhere you want to receive  the data back from the dialog, you'd have to implement it in that class. Simply pass a reference of that into instantiation.

Comment: Maybe I am just not following how this interface thing works. So in my onClick method (called when user presses OK), I would write `callThisFunctionWhenUserClicksOnOkInDialog(mName, mValue);` and then somehow the activity/fragment which implements this interface, will receive the arguments I passed in?

Comment: yep you are right :) just one small difference. You'd be calling,
`mInterfaceCallbackObjectRef. callThisFunctionWhenUserClicksOnOkInDialog(mName,mValue)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107980/discussion-between-gaara87-and-sean-hill).

Answer (score 0):

@Rohit Arya this is what you should know first that fragments needs to declare an interface that must be implemented by every activity that uses that fragment so you can pass data from the fragment to the activity(s)... and must cast the activity displaying the fragment currently into this interface like this in your onAttach method

//@param Listener is the declared interface in your fragment class
        public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
            Listener  mInterface;

```
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
           super.onAttach(activity);

           try {
               mInterface = (Listener) activity;
           } catch (ClassCastException e) {
               throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()`
                    + " must implement DataListener");
           }
       }




    public interface Listener{

       //@param type = data type, cont = variable
 public void sendData(type cont, type2 cont2)
```

;

```
          }
    }
```

make sure the interface declared in your fragment get implemented in your baseActivity then what ever data you pass to the interface using

```
 mInterface.sendData(value, value1);
```

you can get it in the base activity like

```
public class baseActivity extends Activity implements MyFragment.Listener{

//@param cont & cont2 are data sent from MyFragment
@Override
public void sendData(type cont, type cont2){
//do what ever with your values here 

}
}
```

got it now?