# send data from one fragment to show in listview in another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Scenario is: I have two fragments FragmentA and FragmentB.
In FragmentA, I have a simple form and in FragmentB, I am showing data of that form in ListView.

I am getting data in listview but not in real time. Like  first I insert data, then, I restart Application to see data in list.

My question is how to notify change from one fragment to another in real time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data between fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36363185/receiving-data-from-a-dialogfragment-if-youre-calling-from-an-activity-vs-a-fra/36363310#36363310

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use listener in your activity and then notify:
class MyActivity extends Activity {
FragmentA fragA;
FragmentB fragB;

public void notifyB() {
    fragB.notifyB();
}

class FragmentA extends Fragment{
 private void notifyB(){
     ((MyActivity) getActivity()).notifyB();
 }
class FragmentB extends Fragment{
    public notifyB() {
         // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: of course better practice is to define interface, but you use it with the same mechanism

Answer (score 0):

After setting the variable of the FragmentTransaction you can do like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("flag", variable)// You can pass Strings, Int, Boolean. 
//The "flag" is the key to get the value in the other fragment.
//The variable is wat you need to pass to the other fragment.
```

In you new fragment you can get your viable like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String a = bundle.getString("flag");
// now you have te value in the variable a
```

this works in eclipse