# How to pass date back to a DialogFragment

Tags: android, datepicker, dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment which opens another DialogFragment that implements a DatePicker, I want to pass the date from the DatePicker back to the previous DialogFragment and display it on an EditText. I found a way to pass the date back to the main activity, but I cant find a way to pass it back to the previous DialogFragment. 
Please Help.

I used the example here to add the DatePicker:
https://neurobin.org/docs/android/android-date-picker-example/

This is the classes in my code:
MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DialogFragment newFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DialogFragment");
        }
    });

}
```

MyDialogFragment

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
EditText edTo;


View rootView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, container, false);
    getDialog().setTitle("Set Date Range");

    edTo = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etDateTo);
    edTo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

}

DatePickerFragment
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}


@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
       // Do something with the date chosen by the user

    EditText etDateTo= (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv);
    etDateTo.setText("Year: "+year+" Month: "+monthOfYear+" Day: "+dayOfMonth);

}
```

}

This is MyDialogFragment which opens the DatePicker
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNdIp.png)

Comment: There are a couple of ways you can achieve communication between Fragments and Activities: callbacks, [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) and [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: This would be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36363310/2720553 which explains communication using callbacks. Or you can also use EventBus as suggested by @Vucko.

Comment: Quite a comprehensive answer you got there @RohitArya :D Nice!

Comment: you can pass through bundle.

Comment: @RohitArya I tried the example in the link, but how can I send the data from the Activity to the DialogFragment?

Comment: @Vucko thank you, and which way do you think will be better for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventBus solved the problem for me. I used the example from this link incasae anyone faced the same issue.
http://www.cardinalsolutions.com/blog/2015/02/event-bus-on-android
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive event callbacks from the fragment, the activity that hosts it must implement the interface.

```
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
```