# Add item to recyclerView from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I wonder how can i add dynamically an object/bundle from one fragment to another fragment with recyclerView which managed with customAdapter.

So basically im trying to pass an object from dialogFragment to another fragment with recyclerView in it.

its my dialog fragment on click add button :

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

 pof = new ProductForOrder(Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString()),email,Integer.parseInt(serialNum), pTitle, imgUrl);
 cartFragment = new CartFragment();
 cartFragment.setList(pof);
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

in my cartFragment i try to handle the recieved object, and notify adapter about change.

cartFragment :

```
public class CartFragment extends  Fragment implements ListAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

private FloatingActionButton mSharedFab;

private List<ProductForOrder> forOrderArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ListAdapter mAdapter;

public CartFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_recycler);

    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, forOrderArrayList, getActivity());
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    //setList();

    return view ;
}

public void setList(ProductForOrder pof)
{

    forOrderArrayList.add(pof);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

no surprise here, i get npe exception (Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference), even though i do get my objective from the dialog, but i cant add it to my recyclerView in the cartFragment.

Any advise would be appriciated, thank you!

Comment: this might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36363310/2720553

Comment: mmmm i was thinking to implement interface to the frags, maybe if ill change from recycler view to list view it would be easier with the adding?